# Existence of a closed-form for "compression" of formal power series

Tags: formal-power-series

Let "$k$-compression" ($k\in\mathbb Z, k\geq 2$) of formal power series be a map $\mathcal C_k : R[[X]] \to R[[X]]$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n X^n \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n \cdot k} X^n$.

Does a closed-form for $\mathcal C_k$ exist in general? Does it exist in some special cases?

I have found the following special case:

Let $X$ be $\mathbb R$, then for $k = 2$
$$\frac{A(\sqrt x) + A(-\sqrt x)}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n} x^n$$

This is obviously hand-wavy because $\sqrt x$ isn't a power series, therefore its' composition with $A$ isn't formally defined.

This generalizes to $k\in\mathbb Z, k\geq 2$ using the second answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499766/exponential-generating-function-for-1-0-0-1-0-0-1-0-0/3499795#3499795) and composing it with $\sqrt[n]{x}$.

Comment: The geometric series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a trivial example where $a_n \equiv 1$.

Comment: $C_2(e^{x^2}) = \cosh(x)$ is another one.